# Save user specific data in Django

Tags: python, django

I am hacking Django, as I am new to it, to create a website to which user can login and can answer some questions. For logged in user I intend to store their username, question id and response to the question. However, after trying for multiple hours I have been completely unsuccessful. Below I have given snippets of `Models.py` and `Views.py`

`Models.py` - I am copying only UserProfile class and Userresponse class which are needed to create the User Profile and User Response table

```
# Model class for creating user
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

# Model class for getting user response
class UserResponse1(models.Model):
    user  = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, default=0)
    questoinId = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    option = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

```Views.py``

```
def response(request, question_id):
    q = UserResponse1()
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        q.user = request.user.username
        q.questionId_id = question_id
        q.option +=request.POST['choice']
        q.save()

        # Redisplay the question voting form.
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:overallResults'))
```

However, on running above I get following error - `Cannot assign "u'abc123'": "UserResponse1.user" must be a "UserProfile" instance.`

`abc123` is the login name of the user. I am not able to figure out the reason for this error. Any help on fixing this error so that I can write the data to UserResponse1 table, will be very helpful.

I am using Django 1.8 on Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

`q.user` is a foreign key to the `UserProfile` table, so you have to assign a user profile instance.

Since you have access to the user with `request.user` you can access the user profile using the one to one field.

```
user_profile = request.user.userprofile
q.user = user_profile
```

Comment: still get an error - Cannot assign ``"<SimpleLazyObject: <User: abc123>>": "UserResponse1.user" must be a "UserProfile" instance``. Is it possible to define ``user`` object in a way that it just takes ``username`` and not complete `user`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I misread your models. You need to assign the user profile, not the user. I've updated my answer. No, it's not possible to assign using the username string, you need to assign the instance (or its id).

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am still not sure what is going wrong, on implementing your suggestion, the error is ``Exception Value: user has no userpfrofile``